# Change 3d view representation of lamps

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera, light

I am trying to create a more user friendly viewport by changing the representations of cameras and lamps:
Usual viewport with camera and spotlight:
[image]

A mockup of what I'm trying to achive:
[image]

For the camera, I simply used a duplication group I linked from another file. The problem is that using a duplication group on a lamp basically renders the lamp inert.
Simply using a mesh light is not an option since I need specific lamp propertys for example the size.

While a simple solution is preferred, I have no problem with coding something to make this work.

Comment: I think you would need to parent the lamp to a mesh and set that mesh to have no Ray Visibility.

Comment: That would only give part of the desired effect: The user would still have to always select both objects, when e.g. duplicating.